# Recursion and Binary Trees

Tags: python, recursion

```
#Get length of the longest path through recursion
def max_height(node):
    if not node:
        return 0
    left = max_height(node.left) #Base Case based on my understanding
    right = max_height(node.right) #Base Case based on my understanding
    return max_height(left, right) + 1
```

I keep calling the max_height to get the length but I'm getting an error. I've thought of three possibilities:

1) I misunderstand the concept of the base case and I don't actually have a base case.

2) I'm not properly spacing Python code.

3) I'm not recursively getting the height of the BST at all but rather the width of the tree, which is affecting later calculations.

I know it is similar to this question, but the main difference is that I'm really trying to use recursion , where the other question used iteration and merely called it recursion.
[how to find the height of a node in binary tree recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322616/how-to-find-the-height-of-a-node-in-binary-tree-recursively)

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

1. The base case is where the recursion stops and you have one: `not node` (`node == None`)
2. I don't see an issue with the spacing... Make sure you use only tabs or only spaces
3. This does produce the height: the number of nodes from root to leaf along the longest root-leaf path. At every node level, you add `1`, and follow the higher subtree.

   ```
   def max_height(node):
       if not node:  # this is the base case: 
           return 0  # where all recursive calls eventually stop
       left = max_height(node.left)    # <- these are the recursive calls:
       right = max_height(node.right)  # <- function x is called inside function x
       return max(left, right) + 1  # max here, not max_height
   ```

Note that this is merely a more verbose version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322616/how-to-find-the-height-of-a-node-in-binary-tree-recursively#answer-13322724) to the question you linked.

Answer (score 0):

All answered were right but, I faced little problem while writing inside the class;

So, the code goes like this, I hope this helps.

```
    class Tree(object):
        def height(self, root):
            if root == None: #root == None
                return 0
            else:
                return 1 + max(self.height(root->left), self.height(root->left))
t = Tree()
t.height(t)
```